# Which compiler should be used for porting C code to ARM?

Tags: arm, neon, rvds

I am new to ARM. I have written C code,but I'm looking to port the code to ARM which runs on all ARM processors. I am going to develop high end applications such as those which run on smartphones/ tablets. Can you guys tell which is the best compiler for that? I have heard about RVDS, but that seems to be expensive.

My other question is: Can I use Microsoft Visual studio 2008 to program ARM Intrinsic like Neon? Are there any other alternatives for RVDS?

Your advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should look more into what's in ARM's portfolio and which OS you'are targeting?

Answer (score 1):

Several version of the gcc toolchain are available for ARM processors. You need to figure out the exact target for your code such as:

- Which processor or set of processors ? What instruction sets and extensions are supported ? (There are many like `ARMv6`, `ARMV7`, `ARMv7a`). Some of them might have `NEON` support and some might not.
- What kind of FPU support - `hard FP` vs `soft FP` ?
- What kind of OS environment ? `Linux` ? `Android` ? `Bare metal` ?
- Which C library - `glibc`, `uclibc`, `bionic libc` or something else ?

The last 2 are kind of built into the toolchain and cannot be modified. But choosing the exact instruction set and optimization can be controlled using ARM specific `-m` flags in gcc.

And distros like Ubuntu already have the ARM toolchain as part of their repos. You can give that a try too :

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
```